# Is there a command-line alternative to publishing an Orbeon form definition to Form Runner?

Tags: orbeon

I'm curious to know whether there is a way that a form definition can be created outside of Form Builder and then published to run in Form Runner?

Form Builder can become very memory-intensive when building large forms which cause it to crash. This is especially the case when they contain customised actions which need to be edited in manually using the built-in text editor.

For this reason it would be useful to be able to edit the form definition in an external XML editor such as Atom, XML Spy, etc  and then use a command-line tool to build/publish for use in Form Runner.  You could then use the traditional method of compiling software from the command prompt. A form build could even be added to a makefile as a target or dependency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of Orbeon Forms 2016.1 there is no API to publish forms definitions from the command-line. I can see how a "publish" API to which you would send your form definition in XML format could be useful.

In the meanwhile if you want to do some manual editing you can simply copy/paste XML from/to Form Builder, and if you encounter crashes or usability issues please [report them](http://www.orbeon.com/community).

Comment: Ok, thanks for the info.  We are currently using a NodeJs script to extract the forms using Orbeon's crud persistence interface. Then we are storing the form in a Git repository.